# Django Database Objects, Looping through tasks a lot of memory

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to loop through my database (sqlite), and check if any of my primary keys (integer values) between 1 and Max_Value (where Max_Value is the current largest primary key) are missing. They should all be concurrent.

So I have a periodic task that runs through the database, and currently the method is defined as follows:

```
def checkMissing(maxValue, databaseObjects):
    missingValues = []
    for x in range(1, maxValue):
        if(len(missingValues) < 1000):
            if(not(databaseObjects.objects.filter(pk=x).exists())):
                print "Missing:" + str(x) + ", Current Size:" + str(len(missingValues))
                missingValues.append(x)
    return missingValues
```

There's around half a million of items, but if I open task manager in windows, the amount of memory it requires increases 100,00 K per around 5 minutes depending. I've did a len(missing) < 1000 to prevent the database finding too much items, but if the database have no errors, then it will loop through the end causing a mass amount of memory usage.

I've read the QuerySet article on the Django Website:

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists
```

And it does say that exists is a much better way. However, the periodic functions will still crash and complains a memory error.

Comment: Make sure you're not running with `DEBUG=True`, because Django will cache all db queries.

Comment: This does decrease memory usage, however, it would be nice if I can usage debug = true while I'm debugging for errors.

Comment: You could try `django.db.reset_queries()` method to reset the queries. However, it's an undocumented method. I recommend setting `DEBUG=False` if you do not want db queries to be cached, instead of hacking around the Django internals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I ask what's the reason for ensuring contiguity of the keys? Some databases like Oracle don't even guarantee that the keys returned by a sequence object will be incremental, let along contiguous.

Secondly, you're firing a select query for EACH value of x. Basically, in that loop, there is going to be a `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ID = ...` query that will hit the database. That's the reason for the horrible performance.

A better approach would be to fetch all records sorted by `pk` and loop over them and store them in an array or something. Then process the array for missing values.

I haven't tested this code, but this is how I'd go about it

```
for x in databaseObject.objects.all():
    ids = ids + [x.id]
```

Then get the diffence between `ids` and `range(maxValue)` and find the differences.

Comment: Basically I have another server that I want to sync to sqlite, and it seems that most of the keys are sequential. However, the server would always have regular hiccups, so I'm trying not to miss out anything.

Comment: Regardless, you should not do a `.objects.filter(...)` in a loop. It would invoke an SQL fetch for each iteration. Instead try the method I posted above.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could do it this way:

```
def check_missing(max_value, db_objects):

    set_of_pk_values = set( db_objects.objects.all().values_list('pk', flat=True) )

    set_one_to_max_value = set(xrange(1, max_value+1))

    return set_one_to_max_value.difference(set_of_pk_values)
```

Comment: This solution takes only 3 seconds comparing to Ashish's solution, and they both work, but I gave a check mark for Ashish because he came out with a working solution. Probably not the best, but does work.